# Is it possible to create a solution with superoxide?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions

I am not a chemist, and somehow I cannot find any material on this topic, so I decided to ask here.

I am looking to create a solution with a specified amount/concentration of superoxide ($\ce{O2^.-}$). Can you suggest some compounds that will enable me to "isolate" superoxide in a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Potassium superoxide (Aldrich) and an equimolar
>   amount of 18-crown-6 ether used to increase solubility were
>   dissolved in dry DMSO.

[Role of Hydrogen Bonding in the Active Site of Human Manganese Superoxide
Dismutase](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi049888k) *Biochemistry* 2004, 43, 7038-7045

Comment: I took a read through this paper. I don't understand how this has anything to do with producing superoxide in stable amounts.

Comment: @A.I. They create superoxide solutions in DMSO, which is then added to aqueous solutions.  The superoxide is relatively stable in the DMSO solution.

Comment: OK, so what you're suggesting is to mix $KO_2$ and $C_{12}H_{24}O_6$ in $(CH_3)_2SO$, then the whole thing is added to an acqueous solution, which should have $O_2^{\bar{\cdot}}$. Correct?

Comment: OK, this seem s like a good path. I'll accept this as an answer. This [article](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0014579381807971/1-s2.0-0014579381807971-main.pdf?_tid=655afef0-9f87-11e6-a2ce-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1477931635_15a2ce13c0a1374240fde79342c10342) might also be useful for others reading this.

Comment: @A.I. once it's added to aqueous solution,  the superoxide reacts quickly.  See "uncatalyzed, second-order rate constant of 440
M-1 s-1." in caption of Fig. 2.  In the DMSO, superoxide is dissolved as a separate ion and is relatively stable.  In aqueous solution, it is still dissolved as a separate ion, but is unstable, which is why the stock solutions are made in DMSO.